# cast from object to label

Tags: c#, object, casting

what is difference between these codes?

```
public class MyClass
{
    object myObject;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myObject = new Label();
        (myObject as Label).Width = 100;
    }
}
```

And:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        object myObject;

        public MyClass()
        {
            myObject = new object();
            (myObject as Label).Width = 100;
        }
    }
```

in both of them cast is needed and no error happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No *compile time* error happens. At runtime in the second code block, you'll get the exception that an `object` really isn't a `Label` and can't be cast as such.

Because every .NET type inherits from `object`, you can assign any type to your `object myObject;` field. In your first code block, a `Label` instance is assigned to it. You can cast it back to a label as happens at `(myObject as Label)`, because you actually stored a `Label` in it.

Your second code example stores an `object`, which *isn't* a `Label`, so it can't be cast.

Comment: If by "this" you mean magically upcasting an `object` to a `Label`, then no, you can't do that. At `new object()` you have created an `object` instance, a `Label` is something entirely different. Why don't you explain what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to cast an object as label that i've discored while searching for the same solution:

```
    private void modeloUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label label = (Label)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(label.Text);
    }
```